# Tradingview | strategy.exit() with separate exits

Tags: pine-script

I have a problem with this code:

```
strategy.entry("LONG", strategy.long, alert_message='{"action":"order","side":"buy","price":"'+tostring(close)+'"}')
strategy.exit("STOP", "LONG", stop=close * (1 - stop), alert_message='{"action":"close","side":"sell"}')
strategy.exit("PRFT", "LONG", limit=close * (1 + prft), alert_message='{"action":"profit","side":"sell"}')
```

**loss/profit have the same stop/limit problem*.

Only the first exit works, in this case, only "STOP". I need these two separate to send to the **webhook**.

I tried to use **strategy.order()** to make my "PRFT" however, the result in the backtest is very different.

I cannot use the **alertcondition()** because it is only triggered after the candle closes.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you find:

```
// @version=4
strategy("strategy")

stop = 0.05
prft = 0.05

strategy.entry("LONG", strategy.long, alert_message='{"action":"order","side":"buy","price":"'+tostring(close)+'"}')
if strategy.position_size != 0
    strategy.order("STOP", false, qty = strategy.position_size, oca_name = "exit long", oca_type = strategy.oca.reduce, stop=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - stop), alert_message='{"action":"close","side":"sell"}')
    strategy.order("PRFT", false, qty = strategy.position_size, oca_name = "exit long", oca_type = strategy.oca.reduce, limit=strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + prft), alert_message='{"action":"profit","side":"sell"}')
else
    strategy.cancel("STOP")
    strategy.cancel("PRFT")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same. One exit with stop and profit but I didnt work. I did try to did it in two separate orders as you, one for stop and one for profit. It still dont work, **I think its a BUG in pinescript strategy.exit() method/function**. My code is clear and I checked the profit and the stop loss values and its all right.

Thanks to Andrey for an alternative solution.